# Snowflake SQL Time Breakdown

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a timestamp for when an incident occurred and the downtime associated with that timestamp (in minutes). I want to break down this table by minute using Time_slice and show the minute associated with each slice. For example:

```
Time   Duration
11:34    4.5
11:40    2
```

to:

```
time    Duration
11:34     1
11:35     1
11:36     1
11:37     1
11:38     0.5
11:39     1
11:40     1
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: is this snowflake SQL or TSQL?

Comment: Snowflake @SimeonPilgrim

Comment: cool, I will remove the `TSQL` tag then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are fine with the same minute being listed many times if the input time + duration over lap, then you can do this.

```
WITH big_list_of_numbers AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4())-1 as rn
    FROM generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000)
)
SELECT 
    DATEADD('minute', r.rn, t.time) AS TIME
    IFF(r.rn > t.duration, r.rn - t.duration, 1) AS duration
FROM table AS t
JOIN big_list_of_numbers AS r
    ON t.duration < r.time
ORDER BY 1
```

if you want the total per minute you can put a grouping on it like:

```
WITH big_list_of_numbers AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) as rn
    FROM generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000)
)
SELECT 
    DATEADD('minute', r.rn, t.time) AS TIME
    SUM(IFF(r.rn > t.duration, r.rn - t.duration, 1)) AS duration
FROM table AS t
JOIN big_list_of_numbers AS r
    ON t.duration < r.time
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

The GENERATOR needs fixed input, so just use a huge number, it's not the expensive. Also SEQx() function can (and do) have gaps in them, so for data where you need continuous values (like this example) the SEQx() needs to be feed into a ROW_NUMBER() to force non-distributed allocation of numbers.

Comment: you're joining t.duration < r.time. There is no time column in table r. Is that supposed to be r.rn or t.time?

Comment: Got it! A few changes:  IFF(r.rn>tt.duration,1-(rn-tt.duration),1) AS duration     and    JOIN big_list_of_numbers AS r ON tt.duration>=(r.rn-1)

Comment: ah, sorry, this was just typed in without being ran at all. So yes it will have a couple rough edges

Comment: Ah yes, ROW_ NUMBER starts at 1 (had thought 0). I don't think the join want to be `>=` as a duration of 5 and 12:00 is the minutes `12:00,12:01,12:02,12:03,12:04` but not the minutes of `12:05`